# Wordpress - Adding TinyMCE on Frontend into jQuery UI widget

Tags: wordpress, jquery-ui, tinymce, accordion

I'm creating a Wordpress App. It consists on using custom fields on custom type, for managing personal projects.

My issue: I want to add the admin editor (tinyMCE) on frontend. Considering that I can have many textareas that will begin TinyMCE editors. So, I used this code:

PHP (on theme functions.php):

```
// TINY-MCE EDITOR ON FRONTEND
add_filter('wp_head','add_tinymce_editor');

function add_tinymce_editor(){
    wp_admin_css('thickbox');
    wp_enqueue_script('wp-tinymce');
    wp_enqueue_script('tinymce');
    wp_enqueue_script('editor');
    add_thickbox();
}
```

JS (on theme single-projects.php):

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
    // EDITORS
    tinyMCE.init({
        mode : "specific_textareas",
        theme : "simple", 
        editor_selector :"tinymce_enabled"
    });
 });
```

On JS I set the "editor_selector" with a Class for all textareas that will begin tinyMCE editors. I cannot assign a single ID for each textareas because these can be 4 or 5 or 6, or more!!!

HTML: (on theme single-projects.php):

```
<textarea name="new-task-description" id="new-task-description"
    class="tinymce_enabled required"></textarea>
```

Each textarea is present on Jquery UI Accordions.

Now, my problem is, on Firebug (or browser console) I get this error:

```
tinyMCE is not defined
```

What's wrong?

thanks in advance!!!

Answer (score 1):

With Wordpress 3.3 you can use `wp_editor()` which is a lot easier.

http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_editor

The right way to include scripts is `add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'tinymce_editor');`

Comment: This could be right, but in my case, wp_editor() cannot be used because it expect I assume an ID as selector for my textarea. Rather than, I need to use a Class as selector.

Comment: I need to know which parameter I need to use with "wp_enqueue_script" for add tinyMCE script.

Comment: I've tried again to insert manually the script tiny_mce.js on the header of theme. Now I don't get any error, instead I cannot see the editor on frontend...

Comment: I don't think there is anyway of using Wordpress' version tinymce by just using wp_enqueue_script. The version of tinymce used by wordpress needs to be setup by the _WP_Editors class (class-wp-editor.php). You may need to use a separate instance of tinymce on your site for what you want.

Answer (score 0):

If tinymce is not defined the file tiny_mce.js has not been loaded on the page. Make sure the file gets loaded eigther directly or with the means wordpress offers.